# AsyncRead wrapper over sync read

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I met this problem while implementing AsyncRead over a synchronized read to adjust to the async world in Rust.

The sync read implementation I'm handling is a wrapper over a raw C sync implementation, much like the `std::fs::File::read`; therefore I would use `std::io::Read` for simplicity hereafter.

Here's the code:

```rust
use futures::{AsyncRead, Future};
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::task;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Result;

struct FileAsyncRead {
    path: String
}

impl AsyncRead for FileAsyncRead {
    fn poll_read(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Poll<Result<usize>> {
        let path = self.path.to_owned();
        let buf_len = buf.len();
        let mut handle = task::spawn_blocking(move || {
            let mut vec = vec![0u8; buf_len];
            let mut file = File::open(path).unwrap();
            let len = file.read(vec.as_mut_slice());
            (vec, len)
        });

        match Pin::new(&mut handle).poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(l) => {
                let v_l = l.unwrap();
                let _c_l = v_l.0.as_slice().read(buf);
                Poll::Ready(v_l.1)
            }
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

The current implementation is creating a new vector of the same size with the outer `buf: &mut [u8]` each time because of :

```
`buf` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

 buf: &mut [u8],
    |                --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
```

My question is:

1. Is that possible to avoid the vector creation in `spwan_blocking` and mutate the `buf` in `poll_read`? To avoid vector allocation as well as copying?
2. Is there a better way to express this "wrapper" logic instead of `spawn_blocking` as well as `Pin::new(&mut handle).poll(cx)`? What's the more idiomatic way to do this in Rust?

Comment: which version of tokio?
I'm confused a bit, because [here](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.11.0/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html) it has tokio::io::ReadBuf instead of [u8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is odd about this code:

1. If this code is called once, it will likely return Poll::Pending, because spawn_blocking takes time to even start a task.
2. If this is called multiple times, then it creates multiple unrelated tasks reading the same part of the file and potentially ignoring the result due to (1), which is probably not what you want.

What you could do to fix this is to remember the task inside the FileAsyncRead struct first time you create it, and then on the next call only start a new task if needed, and poll the existing task.

With this API you have it doesn't seem possible to avoid double buffering, because since your API is blocking, and the ReadBuf buffer is not shared, you need to do a blocking read into some other buffer, and then copy the data over when a new non-blocking call `poll_read()` arrives.

Comment: It would be nice to include the code that solves this question into the answer.